# Django Forms - How to create a "Save and New" button?

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way in Django Forms that I could implement a button "Save and New"?

For example: 
I'm registering a new Book, I have both "Save" and "Save and New" buttons in the HTML template.

The "Save" button behaves normally. You put the data in the form fields, click on it, the new object is created and saved and then redirects to the list of books.

But I would like that the "Save and New" button redirects to the same form creation page after clicked.

Plese, how could I do that? I didn't find anything about this in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could check on your view which input was pressed, and depending on it, redirect to the list or to a new blank form.